# How to use property values within downloadUrl in Wix Burn

Tags: windows, wix, burn, wix3.10

I need to create a download URL in wix burn based on the user inputs to download a MSI package. I am setting the properties as below and properties set into those variable without a problem when I give them as inputs while creating the .exe package.

```
<Variable Name="PROTOCOL" Value="!(wix.Protocol)" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
<Variable Name="SOURCE" Value="!(wix.Source)" bal:Overridable="yes"/>
```

But the problem is when I use these properties inside the downloadUrl attribute of the MsiPackage element actual values of the properties will not be taken. Burn just recognize them as [PROTOCOL] and [SOURCE]. Following is my MsiPackage element.

```
 <MsiPackage Id="SSCE" Name="SQL Server Compact Edition" SourceFile="../PackageRepo/SQLCE 3.5/SSCERuntime-ENU.msi" Cache="no" Vital="yes" Compressed="no" ForcePerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes"
      DownloadUrl="[PROTOCOL]://[SOURCE]/PackageRepo/SQLCE 3.5/SSCERuntime-ENU.msi" InstallCondition="(NOT SSCERuntimeVersion) AND (NOT SSCERuntimeServicePackLevel)"/>
```

Because of this file is not downloading.
So can anyone please tell me how to use the property values inside the MsiPackage element's downloadUrl attribute.